# Замена шрифта на joomla сайте

Tags: joomla, шрифты

Как поменять шрифт **только для русской** версии сайта на joomla?
Желательно максимально доступное объяснение или ссылку на пошаговый гайд.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам просто надо динамически получить активный язык в коде и через него вставить стили, например:

В шаблоне , `index.php`  для `BODY`  устанавливаете класс

```
$lang  = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(); /* результат будет ru-RU*/
<body class="lang_<?php echo $lang?>">
....
</body>
```

и уже в стилях можете прописать:

```
    body.lang_ru-RU {
    .....
    }
   /*  или  */ 
    .lang_ru-RU p{
    ....
    }
```